# How to bookmark a project location in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2008, version-control, tfs

How can I bookmark a project in TFS for quick access. we have a huge project repository with branching and many levels of hierarchy. I'm looking for some way to mark my favorites projects in Team Explorer
Environment: TFS 2008, VS 2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Team Explorer has a "Favorites" mechanism, however it only functions for Team Explorer nodes (such as Reporting or Documents folders) and not a position in Source Control Explorer.

If you want shortcuts to Visual Studio projects then I'd recommend you download the files in the usual way to your local hard drive and then create shortcuts to the .sln files etc on your desktop or something.  Not exactly rocket science but does it get you what you need?

Comment: What do you mean "across the systems" - do you mean across clients machines so that you have the same bookmarks where-ever you log in or that you would like your bookmarks to be shared between the team?

Comment: second one. to be shared between the team

Comment: That would only work if every memebr of the team had the same location mapped for your Workspaces!

Answer (score 0):

You can look for addons but the most effective thing you can do for everyone concerned is vote that such functionality will be added.  After all this time it still doesn't exist.

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/6968507-bookmarks-for-tfs-source-control-explorer

Comment: this link is dead now